# Как использовать константу в HEREDOC-синтаксисе (<<<) PHP

Tags: php

В таком выводе, переменная выводится так: `{$var}`; а как можно вывести константу, кроме того как присвоить её в переременную?

```
<<<HTML
константа
HTML;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10041243/4223982 ... https://repl.it/D8Cs

Comment: Хередок не стоит использовать в принципе. Пользы от него никакого, а проблем много.

Comment: Да уж, даже `ob_start(); ?> ... <? $content = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();` красивее гораздо выглядит)